# Why is there an "s" in "He says...", "he comes...", etc.?

Tags: verbs, nouns, verb-forms

Most of the time I hear:

"He says...", "he comes...", etc.

Example:

- He says he's going home
- He comes home late

I'm particularly concerned about the 's' and its meaning in the context.

Comment: Are you asking for when to use which tense? In that case you please consult some grammar book or you can search the topics of tense on Internet. You are always welcome to ask specific questions regarding tenses. Your question is not clear. Some correction - 1. you can say "Some times I hear" or "most of the time I hear" or "many times I hear" 2. He says (plural)? :O please clarify? 3. Use proper punctuation. 4. Give a proper title and it needs to be correct.

Comment: Hope that's understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **s** is for the third person singular:

1. I come home.
2. You come home.
3. He **comes** home.

Answer (score 0):

> He says he's coming home.

Who says?

I say? You say? They say? We say?

He says? She says? It says?

The 's' at the end conveys the present tense third person singular.
It helps you know that he said that.